# Regex for parsing some html name and values attribute

Tags: java, regex

I am parsing some `name` and `values` tag from a `HTML` page using `Regex`. However my `regex` is not returning all the required values.. Below is the snippet of html page-

```
<input style="display: none;" name="hiddenAction" value="myval" type="hidden">
<input name="ml_uiss" id="ml_uiss" value="aba972kd82lw" type="hidden">
<input style="display: none;" name="Key" id="Key" value="56n8f48jfn98cwnc38c398nc83nx2b9c32n.an24" type="text">
<input name="AvKbkGPQr" class="iswickEnabled input" maxlength="10" id="AvKbkGPQr" onkeyup="javascript:checkIt(this);" onkeydown="javascript:checkIt(this);" onchange="javascript:checkIt(this);" value="1234567890" onfocus="this.value='';" type="text"> <input name="PjbkAPker" class="iswickEnabled input" maxlength="10" id="PjbkAPker" onkeyup="javascript:checkIt(this);" onkeydown="javascript:checkIt(this);" onchange="javascript:checkIt(this);" type="text"> 
<input id="timeCheck" name="timeCheck" value="23:38:20" type="hidden">
<input name="isDone" id="isDone" value="prq" type="hidden">
```

Below is the code with `regex`-

```
String reg = "<input.*name=['\"](\\w+)['\"].*\\svalue=['\"]([\\w:.\\s]+)['\"].*(<input name=\"(\\w+)\")?";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(reg);
Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
while (m.find()) {
    String match1 = m.group(1);
    String match2 = m.group(2);
    String match3 = m.group(3);
    String match4 = m.group(4);
    System.out.println("[" + match1 + "][" + match2 + "][" + match3+ "][" + match4 + "]");
}
```

The output is below-

```
[hiddenAction][myval][null][null]
[ml_uiss][aba972kd82lw][null][null]
[Key][56n8f48jfn98cwnc38c398nc83nx2b9c32n.an24][null][null]
[AvKbkGPQr][1234567890][null][null]
[timeCheck][23:38:20][null][null]
[isDone][prq][null][null]
```

In the 4th line of `HTML` content, it is having two `input name` tag, because of which, this `regex` is not picking the 2nd  `input name` which is PjbkAPker (This is missing in output). Rest of the things are fine.
I want to get the second `input name` also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1679863

Comment: Pay special attention to the top answer in the question linked by Rohit.

Comment: Also readworthy: [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse [X]HTML.  Use a library with a proper parser (such as [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Parsing X/HTML with regular expressions is a bad idea<sup>TM</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/244128).

Try using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) instead:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(htmlString);
Elements inputs = doc.select("input");
for (Element el : inputs) {
  Attributes attrs = el.attributes();
  System.out.print("ELEMENT: " + el.tagName());
  for (Attribute attr : attrs) {
    System.out.print(" " + attr.getKey() + "=" + attr.getValue());
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```